# How to sort user input to text files in Java?

Tags: java

I have a program taking user input and setting students in a text file, I want to sort these students in separate text files using the grade average

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class NewClass2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       
        
        String recOut = "";
        String delimiter = ",";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int QUIT = 999;
       
        NewClass1 student = new NewClass1();
       
        try
        {    
            
           
            System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
            student.setStudentId(input.nextInt());
           
            while(student.getStudentId() != QUIT)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Student Last Name: ");
                student.setLastName(input.next());
               
                System.out.println("Enter Student First Name: ");
                student.setFirstName(input.next());
               
                System.out.println("Enter Student Grade Point: ");
                student.setGradePoint(input.nextDouble());
               
                
               
                
                
                if(student.getGradePoint()>=3.6)
                {
                    Path fileOut = Paths.get("HonorsStudentList.txt");
                    OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(fileOut, CREATE));
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
                    recOut = student.getStudentId() + delimiter + student.getLastName() + delimiter + student.getFirstName() + delimiter + student.getGradePoint();
                    writer.write(recOut, 0,recOut.length());
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.close();
                    
                }
                
                if(student.getGradePoint()<3.6 && student.getGradePoint()>=2.0)
                {
                    Path fileOut = Paths.get("GoodStandingStudentList.txt");
                    OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(fileOut, CREATE));
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
                    recOut = student.getStudentId() + delimiter + student.getLastName() + delimiter + student.getFirstName() + delimiter + student.getGradePoint();
                    writer.write(recOut, 0,recOut.length());
                    writer.newLine(); 
                    writer.close();
                    
                }  
                if(student.getGradePoint()<2.0)
                {
                    Path fileOut = Paths.get("ProbationStudentList.txt");
                    OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(fileOut, CREATE));
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
                    recOut = student.getStudentId() + delimiter
                            + student.getLastName() + delimiter
                            + student.getFirstName() + delimiter
                            + student.getGradePoint();
                    writer.write(recOut, 0,recOut.length());
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.close();
                    
                }
                
                System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
                student.setStudentId(input.nextInt());
            }
            
                
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("<<Something bad happened!>>");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I've been experimenting with if statements but that's not working because I can't close the writer correctly causing it to only take in one line then stopping.

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with how you're closing the file but with how your opening the file. Every time you're opening the file you are creating a new file and writing one line, then closing it, which is overwriting the old file that existed before. What you want to do is create the file if it does not exist, but if it does exist append one line.

Simply change

```
Files.newOutputStream(fileOut, CREATE)
```

to

```
Files.newOutputStream(fileOut, CREATE, APPEND)
```

Alternatively, you could open/close the files outside the loop or use “try with resources” too.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are only three files, it is probably the easiest to open all three writers at once at the start and keep them open until the end.

If you don't want to close the writers manually (ans at least java 7 or 8 i think), you can use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Btw you probably don't need to wrap the OutputStream in a BufferedOutputStream, since you already use a buffered writer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing each time in file why don't you try to make three lists(one for every grade range you need) and when you have no more students then write them to separate files.
Something like this:

```
 List<Student> honorsStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
 List<Student> goodStandingStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
 List<Student> probationStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
    
// ....
    
if (student.getGrade() >= 3.6) {
    honorsStudent.add(student);
} else if (student.getGrade() >= 2) {
    goodStandingStudent.add(student);
}
else {
    probationStudent.add(student);
}

//while loop end
//write your files
```